# Gradle error with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm getting the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I assumed it meant that I was definint android-bolts twice, once in Facebook's SDK gradle build, and once in my app's build.

Now, these are two different modules, so if I remove one refference or the other, it causes errors in the classes. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** 
The error does not lie with defining android-bolt twice...I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Is you main project contain support-v4 jar in lib if it contain then please remove from you main project which already available in facebook sdk so try to put common jar in parent library project.

Answer (score 0):

Always put common jar in top most parent library project :

**Example**

I use 2 library project in MyMainPorject :

```
1.android-maps-extensions
2.FacebookSDK
```

Now MyMainPorject and and 2 library project required below jar :

```
1.android-support-v13.jar
2.google-play-services.
```

So i will put this both jar on android-maps-extensions (which is my top most library project) libs directory and remove this jar from MyMainPorjectt as well as FacebookSDK if available.

Now android-maps-extensions. add as library project to FacebookSDK and FacebookSDK add as library project to MyMainPorject.